# How can you parse 2 properties out of 1 value with grok in logstash?

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, elastic-stack

**Some context:**

I want to parse the following log statement using grok in logstash

```
07:51:45,729 TRACE [com.company.Class] (ajp-/1.2.3.4:8080-251) USERID called path: /url and took: 1000 ms
```

I am now using the following syntax to parse the complete message:

```
%{DATA:time}\s%{DATA:level}\s%{DATA:class}\s%{DATA:thread}\s%{DATA:userid}\s.*path:\s%{DATA:url}\s.*:\s%{NUMBER:duration:int}\sms
```

Which gives me all the properties that i have defined.

**My question:**

I want to parse this part `(ajp-/1.2.3.4:8080-251)` into a 'thread' property and an ip property. 
The result needs to be:

- thread: (ajp-/1.2.3.4:8080-251)
- ip: 1.2.3.4

How can i do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just add a second grok filter after your working one. Do not put this in your existing [grok filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) because it will finish after the first match.

**Example:**

```
grok {
    match => [ 'thread', '%{IP:ip}' ]
}
```

This obtains your previous field `thread => "(ajp-/1.2.3.4:8080-251)"` and adds a new field `ip => "1.2.3.4"`

Apart from that, I would recommend you to be more specific with your pattern. You used `DATA` everytime which is kind of imprecise. Start with something like this:

```
%{TIME:timestamp} %{WORD:method} \[%{JAVACLASS:class}\] \(%{DATA:thread}\) %{NUMBER:userid} %{DATA}%{URIPATH:uri}%{DATA}
```